# Can someone help me with this conversion problem

Tags: exponentiation, volume, unit-of-measure, dimensional-analysis

I'm taking chemistry this semester for the first time(i used to be a liberal arts person...*used to be*) but now I've moved onto science. Everything was going smoothly here in chapter one until I came across this problem: PRACTICE EXERCISE 2 -  the one about the average depth of the oceans. The question suggests that I use data from the previous Practice Exercise, which is one of the two underlined answers in red. I've been wrecking my brain on how to start. The answer is 1.2 x 10^4 ft.

I've tried converting the 1.36... underlined portion to feet, but I don't know what to do about the 10^9km^3 and how to rid myself of of that exponent on the km. I've tried converting the 10^9km to feet and then working out the cube to get rid of the exponent 3. I tend to come out with an extremely length serious of numbers when I tried to convert everything to feet. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Here's a hint: Think of a cylindrical drinking glass. Suppose you know the cross-sectional area of the drinking glass, and the height of the glass. Can you calculate the volume? What if you know the cross-sectional area and the volume... can you calculate the height?

Comment: So within the 510 x 10^6 km^2, which is the surface area of the earth, is base time height. I have the volume of the oceans in liters and in kilometers. Would I need to perform some operation to find out the height of the surface area, which would mean taking 510 x 10^6 km^2 and finding its parts of base and height?

Comment: So I learned that Surface Area times Depth equals Volume. I don't have depth, which means I divide volume by the surface area and that should give me depth. So when I do, the result is .002666667x10^3km. When I convert that to meters I end up with 2.66x10^3m and when I convert that to feet, I end up with 8.58x10^3ft. So I must be performing an operation wrong. I'm just not sure which one

Comment: You have the right idea! I think your mistake is that you used the entire surface area of the Earth, but the whole Earth isn't covered in ocean... only 71% of the surface area of the Earth is ocean (as stated in your textbook). What adjustments do you need to make?

Comment: Thank you, Doeke! You were very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your volume in liters for the ocean is correct.  Now you can use the figures provided to find the area of the oceans in $\text{km}^2$  If you divide the volume in $\text{km}^3$ by the area in $\text{km}^2$ you get an average depth in $\text{km}$.  Now convert that to feet.

Comment: So the underlined portion with the km^3 is the data I should be using to determine the depth?

Comment: Exactly.  If you have a box, the volume is the area of the base times the height.  You are given the volume and the area.

Comment: I think I'm having trouble with my division then because when I divide 1.36 x 10^9Km^3 by 510 x 10^6 km^2 I come out with an answer of .0026 x 10^3 km and when I convert this to meters and then meters to feet I have 3.280ft.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $.0026\cdot 10^3 km = 2.6 km$  I don't know how you get to $3.28$ feet.   $2.6$ km is much more than that.  You lost the factor $0.71$ that you should be dividing by.

Comment: Are you saying that I should be finding 71% of the surface area of the earth? I guess that's another question: What role does the 71% play in the surface area?

Comment: I really appreciate all your help with this problem, by the way.

Comment: Yes, the 71% is the fraction of the earth that is covered by water, so the surface area of water is $0.71 \cdot 510 \cdot 10^6 km^3$  That will increase the depth by a factor $1/0.71$ because the water is not spread out over as much area.

Comment: Can you refer me to, or give me the language I would use, to refer to finding the percentage of such an extended number? For instance, would the 510x10^6km^3 be called an "equation with double exponents"? Perhaps I would just multiply .71x510 and keep the 10^6km^3 and OH MY GOD YOU HELPED ME ANSWER IT!! THANK YOU!!!! NOW I MUST WRITE EXTENSIVE NOTES ON THIS! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! Is there a way I can reward you?